# Android FCM with data and notification when the app is in background?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application using FCM which is receiving **both data and notification payload**. When the application is in the background the app is showing the notification to the user as well. When I click on the notification I am getting the data payload using `Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();` without any issues.

```
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            String message = b.getString((getString(R.string.json_data_tag)));
            if (message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(this);
                notificationUtils.handleNotification(message);
                finish();
            } else {
                startNextActivity();
            }
        }
```

But when there are multiple notifications, I am able to open the first notification. But when I click on the second notification the app is crashing.

**Stack trace**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.view.alerts.AlertActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: string arg == null at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) Caused
>   by: java.lang.NullPointerException: string arg == null at
>   java.lang.String.concat(Native Method) at
>   com.view.alerts.AlertActivity.onCreate(AlertActivity.java:104) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)

Could someone please help me to overcome the issue?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and some code?

Comment: I remember there are some intent flags, you should use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: @RomanSamoylenko If that is the case, it should crash for the first notification itself.

Comment: what's in `startNextActivity()`?

Comment: @mallaudin startNextActivity() is a method to start the next activity.. I am checking login status in the sharedpreference and based on that it will go to user registration page or main Activity

Comment: `com.view.alerts.AlertActivity` where is this activity?

Comment: @mallaudin based on the content in the data payload an alert will show to the user. AlertActivity is used for that

Comment: I think there is a problem with your `AlertActivity`. Can you post that too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128864/discussion-between-mallaudin-and-somia).